# React-Native Navigation without using stacks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I've been diving into React-Native lately and have made a lot of progress. I know how to use React-Navigation for the most part, whether its `@react-navigation/native-stack` or `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`. There really is no problem when using these as intended.

But in a quest to better understand the tools I'm given I do have this question:

When using the Navigators as intended you end up with multipe screens that "Stack" on top of eachother, or get pulled away when going "back" to the last screen. I have been looking at Twitter a lot for design inspiration of sorts and I can't help but notice that their web-app doesn't use this method of "stacking".

To make this simple I'm only going to talk about the web side of things here but it is pretty much the same on iOS, the screens stack. (Obviously I don't have access to see whether the Twitter app is like the web-app in the sense that it doesn't stack but anyways).

**When using the Navigators properly like in the documentation**

```
<div style="z-index: 0; display: flex;">
   //Screen Content
</div>
<div style="z-index: -1; display: none;">
   //Screen2 Content
</div>
<div style="z-index: -1; display: none;">
   //Screen3 Content
</div>
```

So with this, all the screen components are being rendered technically, just whichever one is selected is the only one that isn't hidden.

What I'm trying to do essentially is have 1 screen rendered at all times with no other screens hidden. When the user "navigates" to a different screen, I want that 1 screen's content to be changed to whichever page they are going to.

The way Twitter works is they have on `<main></main>` container that holds the content for the page and based on which page the user is on, the content within that container changes accordingly. Twitter does use React-Native so there has to be a way to do it. I guess I'm hoping there's some sort of at least semi-official way to do it instead of practically hacking a way for it to work like that. I've scowered the documentation of `React-Navigation' and haven't really seen anything describing anything like this.

**tldr:** React-Navigation "stacks" the screens, they all exist at the same time but only the screen on the "top" of the stack is shown. I am looking for a way to navigate through an app using only 1 screen, and the content within that 1 screen changes according to whichever page the user navigates to.

I have scowered through React-Navigation documentation trying to find anything that describes behavior somewhat like what I am looking for and haven't found anything. I'm expecting to find a way to navigate through an app using 1 main screen that just contains the page contents of whichever page the user is on.

If there is a better Navigation library for React that'll do something more like what I've described, I'd love to be pointed in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is more for single page applications architecture, where you have a single main container that holds the changing content based on navigation, however, React Navigation is designed to stack screens and navigate between them.

### Solution

You can create a custom navigation component, let's call it `NavigationContainer` that holds the changing content, this component will manage which page is currently being displayed and render the content accordingly, something like this:

```js
const NavigationContainer = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState('Home'); // Default page

  const navigateTo = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  const renderContent = () => {
    switch (currentPage) {
      case 'Home':
        return <HomeContent />;
      case 'Profile':
        return <ProfileContent />;
      // Add more cases for different pages
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <CustomNavBar navigateTo={navigateTo} />
      {renderContent()}
    </View>
  );
};

export default NavigationContainer;
```

`CustomNavBar` is another component that contains buttons or links for each page.
 when a button/link is pressed, it will call the `navigateTo` function that receives as props from its parent component i.e. `NavigationContainer` to update the `currentPage` state there:

```js
const CustomNavBar = ({ navigateTo }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigateTo('Home')}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigateTo('Profile')}>
        <Text>Profile</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      // Add more buttons/links for other pages 
    </View>
  );
};

export default CustomNavBar;
```

### Limitations

You should implement deep linking for better URL-based navigation, this will allow users to navigate directly to specific pages using URLs, also, you'll need to handle routing, animations, and transitions manually if desired.
 You might also lose some of the built-in navigation features provided by libraries like React Navigation.